# About facebook permission

Tags: facebook, oauth-2.0, facebook-javascript-sdk

I receive message show below on faceboook developers, my question is if I didn't submit those permission, Can I still use facebook login with "public_profile" and "email" permission after April 30, 2015?

"Your app has recently requested the permissions listed below when people log into your app. Submit them for review and get approved by April 30, 2015 or your app will lose access to these permissions, which may break your app.
Learn more about why you're seeing this.
user_about_me
user_activities
user_location"

Comment: I guess you have add some permissions to your app without asking a review for them. Did you change the set of permissions your app is authorized to use ?

Answer (score 1):

With only those permission, you don´t need to go through the review process. Make sure you don´t ask for any other permissions. Which ones don´t need review is explained in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login#do-you-need-review